# node.js: put asynchronous returns in one object or array

Tags: json, node.js

I am missing something fundamental in terms of callbacks/async in the code below: why do I get:

```
[,,'[ {JSON1} ]']

[,,'[ {JSON2} ]']
```

(=2 console returns) instead of only one console return with one proper table, which is want I want and would look like:

```
[,'[ {JSON1} ]','[ {JSON2} ]']
```

or ideally:

```
[{JSON1},{JSON2}]
```

See my code below, getPTdata is a function I created to retrieve some JSON via a REST API (https request). I cannot get everything at once since the API I'm talking to has a limit, hence the limit and offset parameters of my calls.

```
offsets = [0,1]
res = []

function goGetData(callback) {
    for(var a = 0; a < offsets.length; a++){
        getPTdata('stories',
                  '?limit=1&offset='+offsets[a]+'&date_format=millis',
                  function(result){
            //called once getPTdata is done
            res[a] = result
            callback(res)
        });
    }
}

goGetData(function(notgoingtowork){
    //called once goGetData is done
    console.log(res)
})
```

Comment: because.. you're calling the callback once each time one of them completes, rather than once when both are complete. You're also having a for loop closure problem with the `a` variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example/750506?s=4|0.0000#750506 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323?s=1|0.0000#14220323

Comment: ok, modified to:
`if (a = offsets.length-1) {
                callback(res)
            }`
but I don't understand the other issue: how come I still get 2 sets of results?
thanks so much for helping, this saves my day!

Comment: aren't you wanting two sets of results? `[setone,settwo]`?

Comment: Did you implement the first link i provided?

Comment: I'm still trying to understand it. I just realized I used = instead of == in the correction above so...
with  `if (a == offsets.length-1) {
                callback(res)
            }` I think I'm solving part of the problem, the problem with the a for loop closure I don't know how to solve, I can't seem to understand why, now, `a` will never be equal to 1...

Comment: it's actually never equal to 0, it's always 1 by the time the callbacks happen. that is explained in the first link.

Comment: I am lost... Trying this but doesnt work, 
`function createcall(offset) {
    return function() {
        getPTdata('stories','?limit=1&offset='+offset+'&date_format=millis', function(result){
            return(result)
        })
    }
}

function goGetData(callback) {
    for(var a = 0; a < offsets.length; a++){
        createcall(a, function(){
            //called once getPTdata is done, therefore we know result and can store it
            res[a] = result
            if (a == offsets.length-1) {
                callback(res)
            }
        });
    }
}`

Answer (score 0):

Solved like this:

```
offsets = [0,1]
res = []

function goGetData(callback) {

    var nb_returns = 0
    for(var a = 0; a < offsets.length; a++){
        getPTdata('stories','?limit=1&offset='+offsets[a]+'&date_format=millis', function(result){
            //note because of "loop closure" I cannot use a here anymore 
            //called once getPTdata is done, therefore we know result and can store it
            nb_returns++
            res.push(JSON.parse(result))
            if (nb_returns == offsets.length) {
                callback(res)
            }
        });
    }
}


goGetData(function(consolidated){
    //called once goGetData is done
    console.log(consolidated)
})
```